# I don't understand why these icons won't work

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I want to use the fontawesome icons in my angular app but they just don't seem to work for some reason. I followed the docs but it just keeps on crashing.

Appmodule

```
...
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...,AngularFontAwesomeModule,...]
```

My app is split up into modules:

Image module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ImageComponent } from './image/image.component';
import { GridComponent } from './grid/grid.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';

const appRoutes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: GridComponent }];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageComponent, GridComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule, RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)]
})
export class ImageModule {}
```

image.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img class="activator" [src]="image.path" />
      <a
        class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light"
        (click)="like()"
        ><i class="material-icons red-text">{{ icon }}</i></a
      >
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title">{{ image.country }}</span
      ><span class="right">{{ image.likes }}</span>
      <span class="content">
        <div>
          <fa-icon (click)="Switch()" [icon]="clipboard-list"></fa-icon
          ><fa-icon (click)="Switch()" [icon]="comments"></fa-icon>
        </div>
        <h5>Specifications</h5>
        <p>ISO: {{ image.iso }}</p>
        <p>Shutter Speed: {{ image.shutterSpeed }}</p>
        <p>Aperture: {{ image.aperture }}</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

image.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Image } from '../image.model';
import { comments } from '@fontawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image',
  templateUrl: './image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image.component.css']
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
  private _icon: string;
  @Input('image') public image: Image;
  private _spec: boolean = true;
  private _comments: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this._icon = 'favorite_border';
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  like() {
    if (this._icon === 'favorite_border') {
      this._icon = 'favorite';
      this.image.likes++;
    } else {
      this._icon = 'favorite_border';
      this.image.likes--;
    }
    console.log(this._icon);
  }

  get icon(): string {
    return this._icon;
  }

  set icon(value: string) {
    this._icon = value;
  }

  Switch() {
    if (this._spec) {
      this._spec = false;
      this._comments = true;
    }
    if (this._comments) {
      this._spec = true;
      this._comments = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'.
1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'icon' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<span class="content">
        <div>
          <fa-icon (click)="Switch()" [ERROR ->][icon]="clipboard-list"></fa-icon
          ><fa-icon (click)="Switch()" [icon]="comments"></fa-icon>")
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong and are the names for the normal icons the same as the names for the angular icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you're importing the fontawesome module into the image module, but you're not adding it to the actual imports list...

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ImageComponent, GridComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, 
    MaterialModule, 
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)]
})
export class ImageModule {}
```

Comment: and are the names the same as the web icons?